# Why this set is not convex $1 - x{\log _e}(1 + y) \le 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let  $f\left( {x,y} \right) = 1 - x{\log _e}(1 + y)$  I have been trying to plot the set $f\left( {x,y} \right) \le 0$ in the interval $x>0$ and $y>0$ and the resulting image look realy like convex set to me

[image]

However, from the Hessian ${\nabla ^2}f\left( {x,y} \right) = H = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&{ - \frac{1}{{1 + y}}}\\
{ - \frac{1}{{1 + y}}}&{\frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 + y} \right)}^2}}}}
\end{array}} \right]$, I can observe that

$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{trace}}\left( H \right) = {\lambda _1} + {\lambda _2} = \frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 + y} \right)}^2}}} > 0}&{x > 0,y > 0}\\
{\det \left( H \right) = {\lambda _1}{\lambda _2} =  - \frac{1}{{\left( {1 + {y^2}} \right)}} < 0}&{x > 0,y > 0}
\end{array}} \right.$

This mean that $f\left( {x,y} \right)$ is not a convex function and hence the set $f\left( {x,y} \right) \le 0$ is not convex. But from the picture it looks really convex.

Would you kindly help me how to explain this ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Answer (score 2):

You have looked at the multivariate function $f(x,y)$ and checked whether it's convex. That would correspond to checking whether the 3-dimensional region $\{ z \ge f(x,y) \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is convex.

Instead, rearrange to get $y \ge e^{1/x} - 1$, so your set is the region above  $g(x) = e^{1/x} - 1$, and it suffices to check $g$ is a convex function (for $x \ge 0$), using univariate calculus.

Comment: Then does my function is con vex with respect to x and y on the positive orthant ?

Comment: The function $f(x,y)$ you give is not convex. However the region $f(x,y) \le 0$ is convex.

Comment: Thank you Mr FlipTack, I have upvoted your answer. Can I ask you that If I optimize a linear function over the region $f\left( {x,y} \right) \le 0$, is this a convex optimization problem ?